# Open multiple windows and Dynamically write to them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to open multiple windows/tabs and dynamically write different content to them.

This is what I currently have:

```
var x = window.open('', 'window'+$wc);
$(x.document.body).html("<div class='container' id='c'><pre id='x' /></div>");
var ele = x.document.getElementById("x");
ele.innerText = asString;
ele = x.document.getElementById("c").style.display = "inline";
x.document.close();
$wc = $wc + 1; // window count that I confirmed actually iterates
```

This code is nested in a function that is called multiple times in a for loop. `asString` is a string containing xml tags which changes for each loop interation. `'window'+$wc` is the unique name for each window as suggested in other SO posts. The first iteration works fine and it opens a new window and writes the content to it, but I run into an error on the second iteration:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
at addTopicXml (selfServices.asp:1464)
at String.<anonymous> (selfServices.asp:1320)
at Function.n.extend.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.<anonymous> (selfServices.asp:1313)
at Function.n.extend.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at genXML (selfServices.asp:1312)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (selfServices.asp:206)
```

which referrs to the line:

```
$(x.document.body).html("<div class='container' id='c'><pre id='x' /></div>");
```

as the error (only encountered after the second iteration).

Comment: Interestingly enough, it wouldn't work on a localhost instance of this web app (IIS 7.5), but when I deploy to a development server, running IIS 7, it works. Any ideas?